# Hibernate event listener java configuration

Tags: hibernate, event-listener

How can I configure hibernate event listeners "post-insert", "post-delete", "post-load", "post-update" in java configuration? Either thru annotations or using Spring IOC? Also, is there a way to configure for a specific entity rather than in the method checking instanceof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JPA annotations @PostLoad, @PostPersist, @PostRemove, @PostUpdate, @PrePersist, @PreRemove, @PreUpdate in void methods without parameters inside your entity class. They will be called when the event is performed for a specific entity.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/index.html?javax/persistence/package-summary.html

Comment: thx. Any ideas how to use post load for the following code? http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1395          final NestedSetNode node = (NestedSetNode) event.getEntity();
        node.setPreviousParent(node.getParent());
        new InsertNestedSetOperation(
                (NestedSetNode<?>) event.getEntity()).execute(event.getSession());

Comment: You mean, other than what is discussed in that JIRA? No, sorry.

Comment: Created separate question for listener that requires session http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683820/how-to-create-hibernate-event-listener-that-requires-hibernate-session-using-anno

Comment: Warning: this only works when you access Hibernate through JPA. If you use the Hibernate Session object directly, those annotations are ignored.